# Integrate Bootstrap Tabs with Existing Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tabs

I have this small web application which is working fine. I want to add bootstrap tab control now. [Visit this link](http://tutsme-webdesign.info/tutorials/navs/pills_stacked_panesright.html) for a description of what I am trying to do.

Application structure is like this: I have **Page1.jsp, Page2.jsp, Page3.jsp**. And now I have added **index.jsp** in which I have placed a bootstrap tab control which in turn points to these pages. My index.jsp looks like this.

```
         <body>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-md-2">
               <li class="active"><a href="#main_page" data-toggle="pill">Main Page</a></li>
               <li><a href="#page1" data-toggle="pill">Page1</a></li>
               <li><button id="btn_page2" class="float-left submit-button" onclick="location.href='redirect:page2'">Page2</button></li>
               <li><a href="#page3" data-toggle="pill">Page3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#test_tab" data-toggle="pill">Test Tab</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content col-md-10">

            <div class="tab-pane" id="main_page"> <p>This area belongs to the MAIN PAGE</p></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="page1"> <p>This area belongs to the PAGE 1</p></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="page2"> <p>This area belongs to the PAGE 2</p></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="page3"> <p>This area belongs to the PAGE 3</p></div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              function GotoPage2()
              {
                var Page2_Button = document.getElementById("btn_page2");
                Page2.location.href = "redirect:page2";
              }
             </script>
         </body>
```

As you might have noticed, I have tried different combinations. Placing a button as well and then using java script to redirect. I have even tried placing all the JSP code of **Page 1.jsp** into **DIV** tab-pane with **ID = page1**. But that still does not invoke the Spring MVC controller.

So I want to try following two approaches
**1-** When Page1 button/link is clicked, I want to call/include the Page1.jsp and the controller should be invokable.
**2-** If Option 1 is not feasible, I want to copy all the code the respective tab-pane and the controller should be invokable from it.

Option 1 looks more neat and clean to me. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for any input.

Comment: Instead of `href="#page1"`, how about giving the actual url of the page, like `href="<c:url  value='/page1'">`?

Comment: @Sanjay well I have tried your answer and other variations of it. Some of them are **value="page1"**, **value="/redirect:page1"**, **value="redirect:page1"**. All of them lead to nothing. Single quotes also used instead of double quotes.